# 3D Physics / Transforms animation tool

Tags: animation, 3d, editor, transform, physics

I'm searching a 3D physics / transforms animation editor. It should be able to import 3D meshes from OBJ or FBX, then it should be able to animate transforms. I need such a tool for my 3D Games, where many dynamic and inorganic elements appear, like: doors, traps, robots, lifts, and so on. WHere I can find such a tool? Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: This seems much more suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Try Blender. It's an open-source software for 3d modelling, texturing, animation, etc.

Blender supports physical simulations using well-known Bullet physics engine:
http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-240/bullet-physics/

Comment: I know Blender, but how to export non-skeletal animations to my game? I mean transform animations like position, rotation and scale of particular objects? Do I need to write special exporter script in python for that?

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/DirectX_Exporter .x format supports animations and it's widely-spread. I hope it'll help you. At least, this script can be used as a base of your own exporter